# sql dependency Issue - Notification occurs more than one time

Tags: c#, sql, session, signalr, sqldependency

At first I was not using sessions, so every time I refresh this page. notification occurs 1 more time than last time. So I used this (Sessions) technique which helped but now there is one problem, i.e when I left the page for some time (or when the session is expired without clicking on log out button). I login to the application and there it is, it will then create every notification twice.

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {               
                   if (IsPostBack)
                        return;


                    User _userOnLine = Session["CUser"] as User;

                    if (_userOnLine == null)
                    {
                        SqlDependency.Stop(@"XXXXXXXXXXXX");
                        Session.RemoveAll();
                        Response.Redirect(@"~\Login.aspx");  
                    }

                    if (Session["count"] == null)
                    {
                        SqlDependency.Start(@"XXXXXX");
                        SendNotification();
                    }

                    Session["count"] = 1;

 }
```

**Any Suggestions??**

Comment: Put `SqlDependency.Stop(@"XXXXXXXXXXXX");` in `Session_End`

Comment: Thanks for the reply, trying this.

Comment: Didn't work. Still notification occurs twice

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you tu use the SqlCacheDependency to manage your notifications in an ASP.NET application.
You will find informations about SqlCacheDependency here : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9dz445ks(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Do you think it will work the same way as SignalR is doing. Real time Notification?

Comment: Actually you can combine SignalR and SqlNotification. You SQL Notifications is the server side, then SignalR will push the notification to your client side.